# XML connection to the database (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, database

I am trying to connect the XML files to the database but I think that is not recognizing the XML File as I keep getting the error:
**System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: table'**
I am using ASP.NET for the website. The idea is that when I am trying to push the button *Make Changes*, the database should store the XML file content into the database Table called *fileNAME*.
The code of the aspx is:

```
                <div id="pageBody">
                    <!--  lower part of webpage-->
                    <form id="fileChangeForm" runat="server">
                        <div class="container">
                            <asp:textbox id="fileChangeTextbox" placeholder="Enter new news file for the newest news" runat="server"/>
                            
                            <asp:Button runat="server" id="fileChangeButton" Text="Make changes!" OnClick="fileChangeButton_Click" CssClass="cancelbtn"/>
                            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [fileNAME]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" id="logOut" Text="Bye bye... log me out" OnClick="logOut_Click" CssClass="cancelbtn"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

The code of the aspx.cs is:

```
protected void fileChangeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("/packages/Ass2News.xml"));

                DataTable dtfile = ds.Tables["fileNAME"];
                con.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy sb = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                {
                    sb.DestinationTableName = "fileNAME";
                    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("Title","Title");
                    sb.ColumnMappings.Add("Content", "Content");
                    sb.WriteToServer(dtfile); /*the error comes from this line*/
                }
            }
        }

        protected void logOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session["loggedIn"] = false;
            Session["newsXmlFile"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        }
```

The XML file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<News>
    <NewsPiece>
        <Title>SpaceX's Next Starship Prototype Taking Shape</Title>
        <Content>Construction of the test craft is proceeding apace, as two new photos posted on Twitter today (Sept. 17) by company founder and CEO Elon Musk reveal.</Content>
    </NewsPiece>
    <NewsPiece>
        <Title>NASA's Juno Mission Cheks Out Eclipse on Jupiter</Title>
        <Content>All is well on our largest neighbor; NASA's Juno spacecraft just managed to spot the shadow of Jupiter's moon, Io, passing over its marbled clouds.</Content>
    </NewsPiece>
    <NewsPiece>
        <Title>Europe Wants Ideas for Cave-Spelumking Moon Robots</Title>
        <Content>As NASA makes a big push to land humans on the moon's surface by 2024, the European Space Agency (ESA) wants to learn more about the lunar caves that lie beneath.</Content>
    </NewsPiece>
</News>
```

May anyone know what is the problem with the XML connection to the database?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please do some basic debugging before posting a question here.

Comment: `SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [fileNAME]` what's the fileNAME parameter in the `SqlDataSource`?

Comment: @kshkarin fileNAME is the Table that I have created in the database. So SELECT * FROM [fileNAME] I wanted to select all the columns of the table.

Comment: Which exact line of code throws the `ArgumentNullException`? Please give clear details when reporting errors.

Comment: @ADyson  I have just added a comment to show where the error comes from. It is on the aspx.cs code,  "sb.WriteToServer(dtfile)"